# Invalid format issue Joda LocalDate in collection

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jodatime, localdate

Let's say I got an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "history_experience_entity")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HistoryExperienceEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;


@Column(name = "history_start_date")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
private LocalDate historyStartDate;


@Column(name = "history_end_date")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
private LocalDate historyEndDate;

@Column(name = "is_working")
private Boolean isWorking;

..........
}
```

I use Joda `LocalDate` and for two fields I set format like `"20.01.2017"`. 
I send POST request by postman:

```
{
  "historyStartDate": "15.03.2016",
  "historyEndDate": "30.03.2017",
  "isWorking": true
}
```

And there is no problem with this. But when I have a DTO that have a collection of this entity:

```
private Set<HistoryExperienceEntity> historyExperienceEntities;
```

And I try this POST request:

```
"historyExperienceEntities": [
    {
        "historyStartDate": "10.10.2015",
        "historyEndDate": "10.10.2016",
        "isWorking": false
    }
]
```

I get an error:

> nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid format: "10.10.2015" is malformed at ".10.2015" (through reference chain: com.test.service.dto.EmployeeDTO["historyExperienceEntities"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.test.domain.HistoryExperienceEntity["historyStartDate"])

I tried to add the same `@JsonFormat` annotation above the collection in DTO, but it didn't work.

Comment: Never mind i created deserializer.